# Pass -WhatIf flag to all cmdlets being called in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a test powershell script that I am trying to get the whatif flag passed to all cmdlets in the script. In my script I am calling 3 cmdlets new-Item, copy-item and new-customCmdlet. The last one is a custom cmdlet that I wrote. I have added:

```
[cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
```

to both the test script and the custom cmdlet. When I run this proof of concept script with -Whatif the two system cmdlets (New-Item and copy-Item) run in whatif mode but the custom does not. I thought that if a cmdlet had supportsShouldProcess it should get the whatif flag if the script is running in whatif. That is the case for the two system cmdlets but not mine. I have read the other articles about looking at the call stack and I understand how to see if whatif has been set. For this example I just want the cmdlets to use the -whatif flag that the script was run with.

Here is the script I am running with the whatif flag: 
**PS c:> script.ps1 -WhatIf**

```
[cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
param()
Import-Module c:\mycmdlet.dll

New-Item -ItemType file NewItem.txt
Copy-Item item1.txt copiedItem.txt
Copy-Custom test.txt CopiedTest.txt
```

Here is the cmdlet code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Reflection;

namespace poc.whatif.Cmdlet
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Copy, "Custom")]
    public class CopyCustom : PSCmdlet
    {
        #region paramaters
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
            ValueFromPipeline = true,
            Position = 0,
            HelpMessage = "Source File")]
        public string srcFile { get; set; }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
            ValueFromPipeline = true,
            Position = 0,
            HelpMessage = "Target File")]
        public string targetFile { get; set; }
        #endregion


    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        WriteVerbose("Starting Copy-Custom");
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
       WriteVerbose("Copying files from here to there");   
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        WriteVerbose("Ending Copy-Custom");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the [SupportShouldProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdletcommonmetadataattribute.supportsshouldprocess%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute. Also you are missing the call to [ShouldProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ShouldProcess(v=vs.85).aspx) also make sure you look at [ShouldContinue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568259(v=vs.85).aspx) and use a Force parameter as well. See the [required development guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878238(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info.

Rewrite the ProcessRecord:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    if(ShouldProcess("target","action"))
    {
        if(ShouldContinue("Do Stuff","Do stuff to this object?"))
        {
            WriteVerbose("Copying files from here to there");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So while my example code was missing the SupportShouldProcess, I did have that in my real code. What I was missing was the  if(ShouldProcess("target","action")) I added that to my code and now the whatif flag passes along just like I wanted. Thanks for the suggestions everyone this helped me out so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with C# cmdlets, but as far as I can see your custom cmdlet hasn't declared that it supports ShouldProcess, so how would it be able to use it? Ex:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Copy, "Custom")]
```

should be something like

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Copy, "Custom", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
```

And then you need to use the `ShouldProcess()`-method inside your begin/processing/end-methods to actually define where the whatif-message should say and when it should say it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about C# either but the [preference variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847796.aspx) `$WhatIfPreference` seems *very* pertinent for the scope of your question.

> Determines whether WhatIf is automatically enabled for **every command
>           that supports it**. When WhatIf is enabled, the cmdlet reports the
>           expected effect of the command, but does not execute the command.

So if you are just talking about most of the built-in cmdlets that do support `-WhatIf` then I would think it would be just a matter of:

```
$WhatIfPreference = 1 # Default is 0
```